pycharm no reconoce una instalacion de paquetes en miniforge
Estoy creando un entorno en miniforge a traves de un archivo .yml existente, con una serie de dependencias a instalar. Al crear el entorno y luego abrirlo en pycharm hay una dependencia que no aparece a pesar de que si está instalada en el entorno de miniforge. Se trata de ca-certificates. Alguien sabe por qué puede pasar?

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.
